# Chrome - waiting for available socket - recent increase in occurrences

Tags: windows-7, networking, google-chrome

This morning I have had three different users reporting the same issue with Chrome. When loading a site, it hangs, and the status bar says "Waiting for available socket..." Yesterday, someone else had the same issue.

In all cases we were able to solve this by trying a few things:

- closing all open tabs
- going to chrome://net-internals/#sockets and clicking "Flush socket pools"
- clearing the cache (unticking all except "cached images and files" and choosing "the beginning of time")
- restarting Chrome

However, one of the users has already started seeing the same problem within 1 hour of doing all of the above - they have around 10 tabs open, mostly on static pages that are not constantly polling for info (e.g. nothing like Google Sheets, which was a big impact for another user).

The users are all on Windows 7 Professional and are using the latest version of Chrome (v46.0.2490.86).

Note that when they use Firefox, they do not see the same issue, and they have tested on the same websites.

Has anyone noticed an increase in these issues happening recently?

Comment: Is this occurring on a single site? See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23679968/chrome-hangs-after-certain-amount-of-data-transfered-waiting-for-available-soc